# Calling IE from Chrome using registry IE.FTP/IE.HTTP

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer, registry

I want to open IE browser from chrome for some backward compatibility in application.I am partially successful in it.Now Problem is IE URL contains registry name due to which requested site is not opening.when i click call IE i'm getting "ie.ftp:URL" in IE address bar instead of URL.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="IE.FTP:www.google.com">call IE</a>
</body>
</html>
```